# Generate UPDATE SQL statements from a csv file

Tags: mysql, regex, excel, csv, sql-update

Example:

```
User ID, Last Name, First Name, Start Date, End Date
    001, Pudding  , Chocolate , 10/01/2018, 10/30/2018
    002, Cake     , Carrot    , 10/06/2018, 11/07/2018
    003, Pie      , Apple     , 10/03/2018, 11/01/2018
```

And let's say I already have existing users for ID's 001, 002, 003 and I would like to update their Last Name, First Name, Start Date, End Date. The table is much too large to use a plugin such as "MySQL for Excel" because I can't narrow down my search (the example above is simplified)

I had thought to save this as a .csv, open it up in a text editor and try to find/replace text and form an UPDATE statement.. but I am not even sure how to do this exactly.

I would like each row to be turned into this, going off of first row:

```
UPDATE desserts
SET lname = "Pudding", fname = "Chocolate", startdate = "10/01/2018", enddate = "10/30/2018"
WHERE user_id = 001;
```

I would have several thousands of these that I can then run in the database.

Comment: Are you working on Windows? What kind of editor do you use? Notepad++ ? All editors might have different regex implementations ...

Comment: Hello! Yes I am using Windows and Notepad++

Comment: I would use LOAD DATA INFILE ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html ) (which can read CSV files)  to insert into a temporary table (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) and write a update query which joins on the real table and the temporary table on user id.

Comment: "much too large" implies that you should abandon Excel, CSV, Notpad++, etc, as soon as possible.  Plus learn how to write some kind of application that uses MySQL for the datastore.

Comment: To build on Raymond's suggestion, use the "multi-table" `UPDATE` syntax.  The final result is _one_ `CREATE TABLE`, _one_ `LOAD DATA` of your thousands of updates, and _one_ `UPDATE`.

Comment: If messing with regex is undesired, there are free helper sites like (http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) for generating SQL commands from uploaded CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Open Search > Search ... > Replace in Notepad++

Then use this as search

```
\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*,\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s*,\s*(.+),\s*(.+)
```

and this as replace

```
UPDATE desserts SET lname = "$2", fname = "$3", startdate = "$4", enddate = "$5" WHERE user_id = $1;\n
```

Select "Regular Expression" and click the "Search and Replace".

[image: Search and Replace in Notepadplusplus]